# Robot framework handle an authentication popup

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I need to handle authentication pop up in chrome browser with Robot Framework by pressing enter key or esc keys or click the cancel button.
Like this [image]

I'm trying using the SeleniumLibrary Press keys,

```
Press Keys    None    ESC
```

But it doesn't work

Does someone know how to resolve this? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regretfully there's nothing you can do through Selenium here. This window is from the so-called [basic authentication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), where the user is expected to enter a username and a password and is handled at http level.
The control you see - the dialog box - is an OS component, part of the browser executables itself; as such, Selenium cannot interact with it - it is sandboxed from it (on purpose, for security).

There are couple of workarounds; credentials for basic authentication can be passed through the url - if the target system does not prohibit that explicitly. That's done through a special format of the url:

```
http://username:password@example.com/
```

Another one is to use a library for desktop automation - AutoIt, or Java's Robot. But this has 2 (huge for me) drawbacks - the solution is going to be OS dependant (e.g. one for Windows, and different for Mac, Linux), and mainly - you cannot employ it in remote selenium session - you have to have that desktop automation running in the remote machine, with a desktop session it intercepts, and accessible from your execution machine.

Comment: can you try to handle this with Sikuli, its image based automation.
https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/

Comment: @NipunaMadusanka yes, you supposedly could - it's in the category of desktop app automation tools.