# Input text into multiple alert text fields before action

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I need to input text into the two fields in an alert window like this one as an example:

[image]

I've looked at the doc for keyword **[Input Text Into Alert](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Input%20Text%20Into%20Alert)**, but it doesn't seem to consider multiple text fields and actually I can't even get it to accept one text (alert detection goes timeout).

How is this achievable through RF/SeleniumLibrary?

Answer (score 0):

I found this similar question:

[Robot framework handle an authentication popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63259307/robot-framework-handle-an-authentication-popup?rq=1)

I don't know if anything has changed since then, but the accepted answer solves the problem manipulating the URL, even if without using RF+SeleniumLibrary (which I would have preferred).